# TYPO3 Extbase build own Sitemap

Tags: typo3, sitemap, extbase

There are a lot of sitemap Generators for TYPO3 in the TER available. But none of them can handle Sites created by Extbase, which are not shown in the TYPO3 page tree.

**Edit** Thanks to biesior, detailed informations:
Unconventional I switch in TypoScript the GET Parameter for my Extbase extension
`[globalVar = GP:tx_myextension_articlelisting|article > 0]` 
which shows Articles for a selected page. Probably I have to build my own Sitemap, consists of all normal pages plus all my Extbase articles when a visitor calls the /sitemap.xml. But how to do this challenge?
**/Edit**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Describe problem better, there is NO difference between page created by Extbase or by other solutions (if they created properly of course). Compare the records of table `pages` in database and find the differences, then (maybe) we'll be able to give some hint

Comment: this depends on your demand. I did a separate view for the sitemap whose output included the tt_pages as well as the pages I was creating by parameters of my extension. Those were coming from my extension table

Comment: Nice idea, Christian. Could you post some lines how you fetch the tt_pages? Then I can accept the answer as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ts for create sitemap you can add any items. http://www.adick.at/2010/06/01/typoscript-xml-sitemap/. MB this will help

```
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
            table = tx_adprojects_domain_model_project
            select {
                orderBy = title ASC
                languageField = sys_language_uid
                pidInList = 11,12,13,14,15,30
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                stdWrap.wrap = <url>|</url>
                5 = TEXT
                5 {                    
                    typolink.parameter = 123                   
                    typolink.additionalParams = &tx_adprojects_projects[project]={field:uid}&tx_adprojects_projects[controller]=Project&tx_adprojects_projects[action]=show
                    typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
                    typolink.returnLast = url
                    typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                    wrap = <loc>|</loc>
                }
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    field = tstamp
                    strftime = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
                    wrap = <lastmod>|</lastmod>
                }
                20 = TEXT
                20.value = <priority>0.7</priority><changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
            }
        }

  }
```

Comment: A working example for TYPO3 8 with normal pages and news records (tx_news). Using the same source from adick.at: https://gist.github.com/fabtho/837c4424da9d5ce28ae609173426d46f

Answer (score 0):

You could try the extention dd_googlesitemap_dmf: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dd_googlesitemap_dmf

(you will also need the extention dd_googlesitemap).

It's designed to create sitemap für plugins and you can configure it for any parameter you want.

I try to use this extention to generate a sitemap for tx_news articles, for now without success.

**Edit:** it works with a downgraded version of dd_googlesitemap.
So I think this is a good alternative if you want to create the sitemap with an extention and not with typoscript

Hint: if you use 6.2 or newer you need to get the version from github, not the one from repo: https://github.com/dohomi/dd_googlesitemap_dmf

Comment: With dd_googlesitemap there appear unexpected pages in the sitemap. No control about it. And every page must be visited once, so don't forget to spider manually every time you clear the frontend cache. But thx anyway.